# Use an External ResourceDictionary in a WindowsPhone 7/8 app

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have separated libraries for my applications and I want to put ResourceDictionary to keep my default styles in one place.

In my project mylib that is build to mylib.dll i have Styles/General.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
x:Class="gjdapi.Style.General"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
```

I'm referencing it in my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="General">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/mylib;component/Styles/General.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Build for Styles/General.xaml is set to Page.

I found some tips here:

[Use an External ResourceDictionary in a WindowsPhone 7 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875265/use-an-external-resourcedictionary-in-a-windowsphone-7-app)

[xClassNotDerivedFromElement error when adding Code Behind to Resource Dictionary in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370661/xclassnotderivedfromelement-error-when-adding-code-behind-to-resource-dictionary)

[Error using ResourceDictionary in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025152/error-using-resourcedictionary-in-silverlight)

but nothing seems to work i always hit this exception:

```
Message "Parser internal error: Object writer 'xClassNotDerivedFromElement'. [Line: 15 Position: 32]"   string
```

Please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: as stated in the accepted answer to referenced question, your ResourceDictionary cannot have code behind. Remove `x:Class="gjdapi.Style.General"`

Comment: after removing x:Class line it works! :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lisp suggested ResourceDictionary can't have code behind so line x:Class="gjdapi.Style.General" should be removed